# Refresh tables across environments using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-data-tools, ssis-2012, msbi

I am trying to refresh two tables from a higher environment (UAT) to development. Both environments reside on different servers. As the refresh is to be done every month, I am automating the process. The SSIS package fails despite all permissions.

Background:

1. Tables - `dbo.A` and `dbo.B`
2. Database - `myDB`
3. Servers - `SrvD [Dev]` and `SrvU [UAT]`
4. Service Account - refresh
5. SQL Agent Proxy account for SSIS package run is available on SrvD.

I have written a simple SSIS package containing two sequence containers each for a table. Each container contains a truncate, DFT to copy data, SQL Task to log the refresh activity. Once entire process is complete, send out an email to the downstream system. I have scheduled this package from a SQL Agent job.

The SSIS package fails upon running at the DFT with an error which states

> insert permission is denied dbo.A in myDB.

My package uses a configuration file which supplies the credentials for the service account "refresh" for both environments to the package during execution. I have kept the protection type for the package as `EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey`.

I am new to SQL Server and MSBI.

Comment: Seems to me that the problem is that you think you've given the necessary permissions, but you haven't.

Comment: @TabAlleman I tried the same inserts using SSMS, they work. Do I still need to provide more permissions? If you could elaborate if would be great. :)

Comment: The user for your SSIS package does not have permission to insert in dbo.A Not sure what there it to elaborate on there. The error message is quite clear.

Comment: Look like the **Transfer Database Task** is what you need and a lot less work to setup. Of course you need `db_owner` permission on the dev server.

Comment: @Code Different We just need to refresh two tables as they are incremental tables in our ETL setup, rest others get updated daily by upstream files. The tables A & B are refreshed completed in production every month. Thanks for the suggestion though :)

Comment: @SeanLange: This is the complete set of errors I get when the DFT fails -

[OLE DB Destination [2]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "The INSERT permission was denied on the object 'A', database 'myDB', schema 'dbo'.".

Comment: @SeanLange: [OLE DB Destination [2]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "OLE DB Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]" failed because error code 0xC020907B occurred, and the error row disposition on "OLE DB Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

Comment: What part of the first message is not clear? "The INSERT permission was denied on the object 'A', database 'myDB', schema 'dbo'." The user that is executing your package does not have permission to insert into A. Give that user permission to insert into that table. Remember if there is a deny it always takes precedence.